# Python program won't work - very simple

Tags: python, string, numbers, integer

Basically for this assignment I need to convert a name into a 'secret number' by summing the value I assigned each letter. Everything works so far but when I try to sum it up it gives me an error. I think I need to convert the letters into their number form but everything i've tried so far won't work.

e.g

```
total_name =0 for c in end_name
    c_int = int(c)          
    total_name+= c_int
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Here's my code:

```
'a' ==1
'b'==2
'c'==3
'd'==4
'e'==5
'f'==6
'g'==7
'h'==8
'i'==9
'j'==10
'k'==11
'l'==12
'm'==13
'n'==14
'o'==15
'p'==16
'q'==17
'r'==18
's'==19
't'==10
'u'==21
'v'==22
'w'==23
'x'==24
'y'==25
'z'==26

#input:ask user to enter their name
#processing: convert name into all lower case then calculate number
#output: return name and reduction to user

name = input('Name:')
new_name= str.lower(name)
end_name=new_name.replace(" ","")

print('Your "cleaned up" name is:',end_name)

total_name =0
for c in end_name

    total_name+= c

print('Reduction:',total_name)
```

Comment: How does your code work? All those comparisions need to be part of an `if` statement don't they? In other words, what is the first part of your source code? Also, by does not work, what error or behavior do you see?

Comment: What are the `'a' == 1`, etc. lines supposed to achieve? All you are doing is testing if the character `'a'` is equal to the integer `1`, which returns `False`.

Comment: I guess you are trying for the Encoding from `a` to `1`, and so on, Right ?

Comment: You could build your encoding table like this: `values = dict(zip(list("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"), range(1,27)))`

Comment: Maintaining consistent spaces between your operators (such as `=`, `==`, or `+=`) is important for readability purposes. It doesn't completely matter how you do it, but you should have a rules system in  mind when placing spaces. I personally place one space on either side of all my operators except when writing default parameters.

Comment: actually `list` even needed because strings are already sequences

Comment: It's to assign an integer value to each number, I realise now that I was comparing them but even when I wasn't it wouldn't function.

Comment: Could I perhaps use if statements and then have them return the integer value?

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a colon:

`for c in end_name:`

Answer (score 1):

You will need the `ord()` function to convert a character into a number.

The [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) code for 'A' is 65, so you could subtract 64 to scale to your preferred offset.

```
total_name=0
for c in end_name:
    total_name+=ord(c)-64
```

For lowercase, 'a' is ASCII code 97, but then you'd get negative numbers for any uppercase. You could just as well normalize the entire string to uppercase (or lowercase, your choice) before the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach:

```
values = dict(zip("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", range(1,27)))
name = raw_input('Name:')
score = 0

for l in name.lower():
    score += values[l]
```

For the input `Jason` I get the value `59`

Answer (score 0):

```
_d = {chr(k): k for k in range(97, 123)}

inp = raw_input().replace(" ", "").lower()

print ''.join([str(_d[ele]) for ele in inp])
```

Or use sum if you want as sum

```
print sum([str(_d[ele]) for ele in inp])
```

Output:

```
as d f g
97115100102103
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be done in two lines:

```
name = input('Name: ').lower().replace(" ", "")
print(sum(ord(letter) - ord('a') + 1 for letter in name))
```